# Add a link that takes me to my global inbox to emails telling me I have new messages

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, email, email-notification

When I get an email notifying me of new messages in my SE inbox, I’d like it to include a link that gets me either

- directly to my global inbox, or, at least,
- to a Stack Exchange page with the message indicator icon at the top to click on.

I haven’t memorized the Stack Exchange URLs for the sites I use and I shouldn’t have to. It’s several extra steps to switch to my browser and look up a bookmark, etc. when just a link in the email would do it all.

Comment: Related: [Plaintext part of notification mails is broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134985/238706)

Comment: I don't remember the circumstances from 2 years ago, but the email I got today had a link which took me directly here, so maybe this is not an issue any more.

Comment: That’s the case of the HTML version of the email, not the plaintext version, @Joe. See the question I linked to in my previous comment.