# Plaintext part of notification mails does not link to comments and is otherwise broken

Tags: feature-request, bug, email, email-notification, plaintext-email

In Mutt, notification mails look like this for me:

```
Date: Thu, 31 May 2012 18:19:25 +0000
From: Stack Exchange <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
To: do-not-reply@stackexchange.com
Subject: 1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334

The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2012-03-28:

May, 31 Cost of synchronization
comment: The other thing that that example shows is that 1,000,000 synchrnonization locks take 0.024 secon...If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may
+unsubscribe from this email.

_________________________________________________________________________
Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site][9].

Stack Exchange Inc. 55 Broadway, 26th Floor, NY NY 10006 <3


[8]: http://stackauth.com
[9]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com
```

1. [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) I think that the “If you no longer wish to…” thing shouldn’t be directly after the comment without even just a space.
2. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Add links to the comments, please.

Comment: The unsubscribe link is no longer a problem as it has been moved below the rule.

Comment: Related: [Add a link that takes me to my global inbox to emails telling me I have new messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133671/238706)

Comment: Unanswered duplicate: [Plaintext notification emails do not link to questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197371/238706)

Comment: It would be VERY useful if a notification email contained a link to the discussion thread. Please add.