# Plaintext notification emails do not link to questions

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, email, email-notification

This is what the text/plain part of a notification email looks like:

```
The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2013-09-17:

Sep, 17 Cannot upgrade bind9
comment: Different error now:
Setting up bind9 (1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.7) ...
 * Starting domain name ...If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may unsubscribe from this email.
_________________________________________________________________________

    Questions? Comments? Let us know on our [feedback site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).


Stack Exchange Inc. 110 William Street, 28th floor, NY NY 10038
```

As you can see, the only link is to meta.stackoverflow.com.

It would be nice if there were links to questions/comments.

Comment: 'There are no links' is also mentioned in this related question: [Plaintext part of notification mails does not link to comments and is otherwise broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134985/plaintext-part-of-notification-mails-is-broken)